# Reference implementation of Nédélec-Elements

Tags: finite-element

Does anybody know of an implementation of [Nédélec elements](http://www.springerlink.com/content/vv750g6576n9p820/) that does not come along with a huge bulk of additional software?

Is there a small library written in a language like Python, Matlab, or Octave? The only implementations I know of are part of larger FEM libraries which are too difficult to learn for the sole purpose of comparing with my own implementation. In the literature, there is virtually *nothing* on how these elements look when implemented, not to speak of example code.

Comment: The link to the paper at `springerlink.com` is broken. Perhaps you could take a look, whenever possible…

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Long Chen](http://math.uci.edu/~chenlong) has built a very compact library called [$i$FEM](http://ifem.wordpress.com), it has a complete implementation of the first and second type of Nédélec elements up to quadratic order, including a very readable data structure for geometry and DoFs, the stiffness matrix assembling(the implementation is similar to the idea shown in [Carstensen's paper](http://www.mathematik.hu-berlin.de/~cc/download/public/publications/paper/CMAMv5p333-361.pdf)), an adaptive mesh refining and coarsening procedure, also the multigrid solver based on [Hiptmair's multigrid for Maxwell paper](http://www.jstor.org/stable/10.2307/2587241), together with HX-preconditioning technique.

For even higher order Nédélec elements which are used in $hp$-FEM, I suggest you refer to the book written by Pavel Solin: [Higher-Order Finite Element methods](http://hpfem.org/~pavel/public/books.html), in chapter 2 it has an explicit representation of the higher order vector elements using the edge vector and the face normal vector, not just for $H(\mathbf{curl})$, also for $H(\mathrm{div})$, and the recursively defined shape functions fall into Long Chen's data structure and assembling subroutine quite neatly.

Answer (score 3):

It's not a minimal complete finite element library, but [FIAT](https://launchpad.net/fiat) tabulates Nedelec spaces (and many other spaces) and [DOLFIN](https://launchpad.net/dolfin) has simple examples for testing. The new [FEniCS Book](http://fenicsproject.org/book/index.html) offers a good explanation of design and implementation. Unfortunately, there is a somewhat opaque "form compiler" so it would take more effort to fully understand every step of the process. On the other hand, the output of the form compiler performs a task that is not difficult to understand.